# Replace to vs replace by

Tags: prepositions

I would like  inquire about the correct usage of preposition to/by after replace. for example:

> Please replace this word to something else.
>   Please replace this word by something else.

Are these two sentences correct? If yes then what is the difference n meaning ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, **replace something to something else** is completely unidiomatic. **Replace by** sounds a lot better and generally would be a better choice of words, but you would typically say that in the passive voice: **to be replaced by something or someone** (e.g. *He was replaced by the new mayor.*). If you want to say that in the active voice, use **replace with**:

> Please **replace** this word **with** something else.